Form is becomes invalid when its dynamically loaded in Mat-Stepper
I have the below code to enable Mat Stepper form at run time. The forms will be enabled based on the Checkbox value in FormCheckbox. My problem is if I didn't check Checkbox1 and checked Checkbox2, then I see FormCheckBox2 and all good, but when I go back to FormCheckbox and now Check Checkbox1 the FormCheckbox1 appear but they never become valid and values are not getting captured in FormGroup. Here is my Code. Can someone please help here?
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
  <div *ngFor="let c of components; let i = index">
    <mat-step *ngIf="c.enabled">
      <div class="form-container">
        <form [formGroup]="c.formGroup">
          <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="c.compNm"></ng-container>
          <div>           
            <button
              matStepperNext
              [disabled]="!c.formGroup.valid"
              (click)="continue(c.formNm)"
            >
              Continue
            </button>
           
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </mat-step>
  </div>

interface ComponentList {
  formNm: string;
  formGroup: FormGroup;
  compNm: any;
  enabled: boolean;
}

this.components = [
      {
        formNm: 'FormCheckbox',
        formGroup: this.FormCheckbox1,
        compNm: Component1,
        enabled: true,
      },
      {
        formNm: 'FormCheckbox1',
        formGroup: this.FormCheckbox1,
        compNm: Component2,
        enabled: true,
      },


{
    formNm: 'FormCheckbox2',
    formGroup: this.FormCheckbox2,
    compNm: Component3,
    enabled: true,
  },

On the Next button click I am modifying the enable property of the array
this.components.find((f) => f.FormCheckbox1=== 'FormCheckbox1').enabled =
        this.FormCheckbox1.value.Checkbox1;
      this.cdr.detectChanges();

Form component code
<div [formGroup]="formCheckbox1">
  <table class="form-table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="form-header">Some details</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="field-label">
            When were you first diagnosed or treated for XYZ?
          </div>
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" subscriptSizing="dynamic">
            <input
              matInput
              [matDatepicker]="adhdpicker"
              formControlName="firstDiagnosedDate"
            />
            <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
            <mat-datepicker-toggle
              matIconSuffix
              [for]="adhdpicker"
            ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #adhdpicker></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="field-lable">
            Are you currently taking any medications to treat XYZ?
          </div>
          <mat-button-toggle-group
            formControlName="takingMedication"
            [hideSingleSelectionIndicator]="true"
            #takingMedication="matButtonToggleGroup"
          >
            <mat-button-toggle value="yes">Yes</mat-button-toggle>
            <mat-button-toggle value="no">No</mat-button-toggle>
          </mat-button-toggle-group>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="field-lable">How many medications?</div>
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" subscriptSizing="dynamic">
            <mat-select formControlName="noOfMedication">
              @for (no of medicationCount; track medicationCount) {
              <mat-option [value]="no">{{ no }}</mat-option>
              }
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

TS file of Form component
ngOnInit() {
    this.formCheckbox1= this.fb.group({
      firstDiagnosedDate: [null, [Validators.required]],
      takingMedication: [null, [Validators.required]],
      noOfMedication: [null, [Validators.required]],
    });

    this.form = this.ctrlContainer.form;
    this.form.addControl('XYZ', this.formCheckbox1);
  }

When i look at the code in console I can see the difference in the class for the form
Go back and come
<form _ngcontent-ng-c946798950="" novalidate="" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid">

First time load
<form _ngcontent-ng-c946798950="" novalidate="" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched">


Could you share stackblitz with the issue replicated, I cant see any forms checkbox code

its a huge code Naren, and difficult to post it on stackblitz. Client info also

not all code required just a single form field with the issue happening for debugging

added form component code and TS file code
